# Google Sheet > Translate String to Function Path

Tags: google-sheets

I am creating a summary sheet in which you can select a column title, and below you will get the Sum of this row.

I have a data validation picker that provides you the options, e.g. column "First Col", "Second Col", "Third Col".
Then I translate it using a switch to "A", "B", "C" (actual columns on the other sheet), and even add the full location, e.g. "OtherSheerB2:B10000".

The problem is how can I try to translate the String representing the column as the function path:
In this example, if you chose "Second Col", I will try `=Sum("OtherSheerB2:B10000")`
and fail :(

Is the idea I am trying even possible? or are there any other suggestion?

Comment: there is a significantly easier way to do this, but it's impossible to explain without some sample data or sheet to use as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I found a solution using SQL e.g.:

```
=QUERY({OtherSheerB2!$A$2:$T$1000},CONCAT(CONCAT("select sum(Col",M1),")"))
```

When M1 contains the number of the columns I want to sum.